# JavaScript function not called when using VoiceOver

Tags: javascript, html, ios, voiceover

I've created and tested a webpage that includes full support for screen readers. It works great with VoiceOver for Mac, but when I tried VoiceOver for iOS I found an issue. When I double tap to trigger a link, the `click` event listener is not called. Instead VO just repeats the `aria-label` I've given it, and it does not announce "button" afterwards. It works when I disable VoiceOver, just by tapping on it. The link is intended to behave like a button, not navigate to another webpage. Is this a VoiceOver bug or is there a problem with my markup or my code?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', triggerFunction);
});

function triggerFunction() {
  alert('testing');
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" aria-label="My Trigger">Trigger Function</a>
```

Comment: Try prevent the default action  `function triggerFunction(evt) {
  alert('testing');
  return false;
}`

Comment: @TamilSelvan Nope, that didn't do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, there is clearly no mouse, therefore you cannot `click`, but what you can do is listen for a `touch` event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', triggerFunction);
    document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('touchstart', triggerFunction);
});
```

Comment: Adding `touchstart`didn't change the behavior. Note that `click` is triggered on iOS if I disable VoiceOver and tap on it.

Comment: Weird, honestly sounds like a VoiceOver bug to me, but I've never made a mobile web app, so I can't be for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Is your link element nested in another element? Sometimes VoiceOver's click event will act on those instead and not bubble down to nested elements.

So for example if your html looks like this:

```
<li id="parent">
  <div id="link" onclick="myFunction()">
  </div>
</li>
```

then try moving your click handler up a level to the parent element.